# Store 2 values in an autocomplete Text Field: ID and Name

Tags: oracle-apex

Currently I display a list of supplier using a Popup LOV but I'm trying to change the field to a Text Field autocomplete. I display the supplier name but store the supplier ID. When I try and change the field, APEX says the wrong number of columns are selected in the LOV query.

Is there a method of holding two values in a Text Field autocomplete? The following query I currently use for the Popup LOV:

```
 SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME KEY, SUPPLIER_ID VALUE
 FROM SUPPLIERS
 WHERE ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'
 order by SUPPLIER_NAME
```

Comment: Amazing how this was not a part of the original design of APEX. It's been available in similar form in EBS for ages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An autocomplete text item does not have separate display and return values, it just has a single value, so the associated LOV can only have 1 value.

Comment: But, it does. See my answer below.

Comment: @NaeelMaqsudov No, it doesn't.  Your answer below is a great idea, but the LOV still only has a single value in it, you've just been creative with the contents of that value.  My answer is still correct.

Comment: Agree. My idea doesn't make your answer incorrect, of course.
I just only want to point that autocomplete text item does not `naturally` support separate display and return values.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, click Edit page and add the following CSS:

```
<style>ac_key{display:none}</style>
```

Then change query for your Autocomplete list like this:

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME||'<ac_key>'||SUPPLIER_ID||'</ac_key>'
FROM SUPPLIERS
WHERE ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'
order by SUPPLIER_NAME
```

Now each line of a list contains invisible KEY value, and you may process `result` event of a form field, extract invisible key, and fill-in hidden field which is sent on submit.

Edit the form again and add some Javascript to the page like this:

```
$("#P99_AC_FIELD").result(function(event,data,formatted){
  if(data){
    if(ac_key = data.toString().match("<ac_key>(.*)</ac_key>")){
      //console.log(ac_key[1]);
      $("#P99_AC_FIELD_KEY").val(ac_key[1]);
    }
  }
});
```

- P99_AC_FIELD - text field for searching value in a list
- P99_AC_FIELD_KEY - hidden field for passing the key selected

UPD:
Also you can put several values into  as separated list, JSON or tags does not matter. OnResult event you may parse them and fill in several (hidden or normal) fields at once.

Comment: Good, but might be a good idea to start of by saying something like "Here is a way to overcome the limitation". +1 anyway.

Comment: maybe i'm too stupid but i have no idea ... i have an autocomplete item with lov (sql query) like yours but i can't hide the id in the search box and i tried your javascript but no success. Where should I add CSS and Javascript exactly? In which form? A static content region contains the items (autocomplete text field and hidden item for id).

Answer (score 1):

When the standard option doesn't cut it, you can always roll your own

Basic jquery autocomplete item (ex http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:26)
(and this is rather rudimentary, but it shows you the basics)

1. HTML Header

   ```
   <script src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.14/ui/minified/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
   ```
2. 2 items

   - P26_EMPNO : will hold the VALUE
   - P26_ENAME : holds the LABEL
3. Dynamic action, Page Load, True action: execute javascript

   ```
   $("#P26_ENAME").autocomplete({
      source: function(req, add){
         //call the page process get_contact_data and put its return in greturn
         //this process returns markup for a JSON object so this can easily be parsed in jquery
         //x01: a temporary variable simply used for passing on a value
         $.post('wwv_flow.show', 
                {"p_request"      : "APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_EMPLOYEES",
                 "p_flow_id"      : $v('pFlowId'),
                 "p_flow_step_id" : $v('pFlowStepId'),
                 "p_instance"     : $v('pInstance'),
                 "x01"            : req.term
                },
                 function(data){
                    if(data){
                       add($.parseJSON(data));
                    };
                }
               );               
      },
      select: function(event, ui){
         $("#P26_ENAME").val(ui.item.label);
         $("#P26_EMPNO").val(ui.item.value);
         event.preventDefault();
      },
      delay: 500,
      minLength: 1,
      autoFocus: true
   });
   ```
4. AJAX Callback process

   ```
   DECLARE
      v_json CLOB;
   BEGIN
      FOR rec IN (SELECT '{' || '"value":"' ||e.EMPNO ||'",'||
                                '"label":"' ||e.ENAME ||'"' -- last entry
                             || '}' obj
                    FROM EMP e
                   WHERE UPPER(e.ENAME) like UPPER(apex_application.g_x01)||'%'
      ) LOOP
         v_json := v_json ||','|| rec.obj;
      END LOOP;

      v_json := '[' || LTRIM(v_json, ',') || ']';
      htp.p(v_json);
   END;
   ```

-> jQuery UI docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

**Or look into using a plugin**. For example, this one: http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/odtug-competition/combobox_208.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution that requires less custom coding.

Create two fields. One for the auto complete name, and another for the ID. The ID is what is stored in the database.

**ID Field**

- Name: `FIELD_1`
- Type: Hidden
- Settings; Value Protected: No
- Source; Type: Database Column
- Source; Database Column: `SELECTION_ID`

**Name Field**

- Name: `FIELD_2`
- Type: Text Field with Autocomplete
- Settings: [choose what you want]
- List of Values; Type: SQL Query
- List of Values; SQL Query: `SELECT [NAME] FROM [LIST_TABLE]`

  - Make sure query provides unique values; no duplicates
- Source; Type: SQL Query (Return Single Value)
- Source; SQL Query: `SELECT [NAME] FROM [LIST_TABLE] WHERE ID = :FIELD_1` For form
- Source; SQL Query: `(SELECT [NAME] FROM [LIST_TABLE] WHERE ID = Q.SELECTION_ID)` For data grid

**Dynamic Action**

- Name: Update ID Field
- When; Event: Custom
- When; Custom Event: `result`
- When; Selection: Item(s)
- When; Items: `FIELD_2`
- Action When True

  - Action: Set Value
  - Settings; Set Type: SQL Statement
  - Settings; SQL Statement: `SELECT [ID] FROM [LIST_TABLE] WHERE [NAME] = FIELD_2`
  - Affected Elements; Selection Type: Item(s)
  - Affected Elements; `FIELD_1`

**Notes**

For data grid, you will not be able to hide the ID column directly, you'll have to un-select the column in the Actions -> Columns menu. You'll have to make sure that the Name data is unique. Duplicates will cause the retrieval of the NAME from ID to respond with multiple values, and will cause errors.